# Why can "docker-compose run" create files outside the container?

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose

I am new to Docker and I am learning Docker with its official docs.

In one [tutorial](https://docs.docker.com/compose/django/), it explains how to create a Django project with Docker.

What I can not understand is the command below.

```
docker-compose run web django-admin.py startproject composeexample .
```

The doc says it will create a Django project inside a container, and those new created files will be in local filesystem.

My question is why those new created files will be in local system if they are created in a container?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because in your `docker-compose.yml` file you're creating an image called web with a shared volume which maps your current directory (.) to /code directory of the created container.

```
volumes:
  - .:/code
```

That means that all files that are in /code directory (the directory where you create your project inside in the container) will be also in your local system under project directory.

Take a look to data volumes in Docker documentation to see things clearly:

https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/

Comment: Does that mean that though the command is run inside container but the files will be created in local file system due to volume setting?

Comment: That's it, files will be created in the host directory shared, in this case . , which is your current directory. 

Any modifications done in your current directory (.) will be reflected in /code directory of the container and vice versa.

Comment: You just need to take care because the container folder will be always overwritten if it exists, and if it doesn't it will be created.

Answer (score 1):

Because in the docker-compose.yml it's defined a volume:

```
volumes:
       - .:/code
```

The "dot" before the colon means the current directory in your computer (host) relative to the Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml. And the /code is the directory inside the container.